# store objects from a third party library in a hibernate database

Tags: java, hibernate

Before I start, I don't have much experience with hibernate. I'm working on an application where I use my colleagues library to display some data. There are recording objects I want to store in my database, so I don't need to create them every time I use a particular function. I would like to read them from the database. First I tried to do it like this:

```
@Entity
public class RecordingEntity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "recording")
    private Recording recording;

    @ManyToOne
    @Column(name = "user")
    private User user;

    public RecordingEntity(Recording recording, User user)
    {
        this.recording = recording;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Recording getRecording()
    {
        return recording;
    }

    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setRecording(Recording recording)
    {
        this.recording = recording;
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getUser()
    {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }
}

public class ImportRecording()
{
        ...
        try
        {
            TapestryDBConnection.performAtomic(new DBAtomicRunnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run(Session session) throws InterruptedException, IOException, SerialException, SQLException
                {
                    ...
                    RecordingEntity recordingEntity = new RecordingEntity(recording);
                    session.saveOrUpdate(recordingEntity);
                    ...
                }
            }, true);
        }
    return null;
}
```

This would lead to: `java.lang.ClassCastException: Recording cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob`

Then I tried it without the `@Lob` and I got: 
`org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: Recording, at table: RecordingEntity, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(recording)]`

EDIT:

I have tried to save the object with converting them into byte[] and storing the byte[] on to the database. Unfortunately it is not possible unless the recording class implements the interface Serializable. I would prefer to solve this problem without implementing Serializable.

Comment: Have you tried to map on hibernate the entity who is in this library?

Comment: No I haven't. Would you tell me how I can do this?

Comment: You're trying to persist a Blob/Clob? @Lob indicates that the property should be persisted in a Blob or a Clob depending on the property type: java.sql.Clob, Character[], char[] and java.lang.String will be persisted in a Clob. java.sql.Blob, Byte[], byte[] and serializable type will be persisted in a Blob.

Comment: I noticed later that both (Blob/Clob) are not what i think I need. The ideal option would be if i could write the recording object as it is on to the database but i don't know if this is possible.